# Create new Simulink project through script

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to create a new `Simulink` project through `Matlab` script.

Please show me how I can accomplish that through the use of syntax commands.

Comment: If by project you mean model, then look at [Creating a Model Using MATLAB Code](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-creating-using-matlab-code.html).  It looks at the very basics - much more advanced things can be done using similar techniques.

Comment: @PhilGoddard I think the OP is referring to a [Simulink project](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-a-new-project-to-manage-existing-files.html), not a Simulink model. As far as I know, there is no command line equivalent for creating a new Simulink project. I think [`simulinkproject`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulinkproject.html) only allows opening existing projects.

Comment: Yeah.. I mean the simulink project, not the model.

Answer (score 0):

As am304 stated, it doesn't appear that simulinkproject can be directly created by a single command.
However, we can implement our own create simulinkproject method.

A simulinkproject is associated with a folder, and in this folder it stores all its project information the sub-folder, '.SimulinkProject'. In this subfolder, all information is stored in a file called Project.xml. If we create this sub-folder and initialize Project.xml, we have effectively created a simulink project, which can be open from the command line.

```
projectName = 'myProject';
s = strcat('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project MetadataType="monolithic">    <EntryPoints Location="Root"/>    <Files Location="Root"/>    <ProjectData Location="Root"/>    <Categories Location="Root"/>    <Extensions Location="Root"/>    <Info Location="ProjectData">        <Info Name="',projectName,'"/>    </Info></project>');
path = 'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Simulink Files';
folderName = '.SimulinkProject';
filePath = strcat(path,filesep,folderName,filesep,'Project.xml');
mkdir(path,folderName);
file = fopen(filePath,'wt');
fprintf(file,s);
fclose(file);

myProj = simulinkproject(path);
```

Replace projectName with the desired name of the project and path with the desired location of the project.

Answer (score 0):

MathWorks introduced a function to do this in R2017a. You can create a Simulink Project file (.prj) at the specified path by calling:

```
proj = slproject.create('projectpath\projectName');
```

Using the output object, `proj`, you can set up the project.

For more information, visit the MathWorks [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slproject.create.html?searchHighlight=slproject.create&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).